# Computing values of a latent variable

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable

Is there an easy way to compute the (standardized) values of latent variables so that it generates a new variable to the dataset.

I am working with Stata. The SEM model builder doesn't seem to offer that option.

Thanks for all advice!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of points:

1. You can compute *a* value for the latent variable, but not *the* value. There are many potential values, all of which work.
2. The variable will be standardized if you standardize the latent variable (which is often not a good idea). Standardize if after, if that's what you want.

In Stata, you use the the post-estimation predict command (just as in regression) to save the estimated values of the latent variables.

Documentation: https://www.stata.com/manuals13/sempredictaftersem.pdf